# Unable to typecast Mock's object when using the AWS SDK and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, moq

I'm attempting to write unit tests around a service which will manage communication with various SQS queues. I'm unable to inject Mocked versions of the IAmazonSQS into my class. I have the following constructor:

```
private AmazonSQSClient client;

public SqsQueue(IAmazonSQS client, string queueUrl)
{
    this.client = (AmazonSQSClient)client;
    this.queueUrl = queueUrl;
}
```

The problem line is the assignment to this.client. I get this exception: `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IAmazonSQSProxy' to type 'Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSClient'.` When I change that line to this:

```
this.client = client as AmazonSQSClient;
```

this.client is set to null.

This is the relevant Unit Test code:

```
public void Setup()
{
    this.mockClient = new Mock<IAmazonSQS>();
    this.queueUrl = "testUrl";
}

public void GetMessageCount_WhenMessagesExist_ReturnsCount()
{
    // Arrange
    var sqsQueue = new SqsQueue<IMessage>(this.mockClient.Object, this.queueUrl); // Calls into the constructor above.
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you self-answered, but I figured I'd give my answer as well.

The problem is that your constructor is accepting an interface, then you are casting that interface to a discrete class. While this works for normal operations, it will not work in your unit testing, because your actual discrete class is **not** an `AmazonSQSClient` and has no relationship to it. The only commonality between `AmazonSQSClient` and your mock object is that they both implement the `IAmazonSQS` interface.

To use the Amazon clients, all you need is the interface. So, change your member variable to the interface, and avoid the casting:

```
private IAmazonSQS client;

public SqsQueue(IAmazonSQS client, string queueUrl)
{
    this.client = client;
    this.queueUrl = queueUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was the typecasting itself. I changed my class to have a `private IAmazonSQS client` rather than `private AmazonSQSClient client`. That removes the necessity for the problematic typecasting and allows the tests to run.

Comment: Was just about to give an answer, but you figured it out. The classes should depend on abstractions (interface/abstract) and not concretions (class), so by having the concrete class as an local variable still meant that the class was tightly coupled to the implementation rather than the abstraction.